# Remove Favorites button from IE8

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, favorites

Does anyone know how to remove the Favorites button that appears to the far left in IE8?  This question is not in reference to the Favorites bar or the Favorites menu.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to Management of the Web, right clicking the toolbar and unchecking the favorites there only removes the favorites "bar", not the favorites "button".  Specifically, the OP is looking to remove the favorites button.

I do not believe this is possible without disabling the entire tab bar :(

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer at this location in the ie8blog.com site:
http://www.ie8blog.com/2009/09/24/hide-or-remove-favorites-button-from-ie-toolbar/

Please be aware that the entire tab browsing feature will be disabled as well if you implement the registry hack!

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Restrictions]

“NoCommandBar”=dword:00000001

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just install firefox! I jest, just right click on the toolbar and uncheck the favorites tab and voila!

Answer (score 1):

While I've never been able to make the Favorite Button disappear, I was able to make it move off of the Favorites Tool Bar using a registry tweak.

Go to :

`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\CommandBar]`

In the key "FavBandRow" change the value to "3" and the Favorites Button will move off the Favorites Bar and up to the Bar directly above.

This then leaves more room on the Favorites Bar itself for more favorites.